# Django error missing positional argument (request)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a webapp with Django and using Djano class based views to call other functions within views.py. I'm fairly new to programming and think I'm confusing myself here.

I'm getting following error:

> make_connection_to_user() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'request'

**Views.py:**

```
from .models import UserInfo

def make_connection_to_user(request):
    current_user = UserInfo.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
    user_token = current_user.access_token
    connection = MyApp(user_token)
    return connection

def get_user_info():
    used = make_connection_to_user().users_get_space_usage().used
    allocated_space = make_connection_to_user().users_get_space_usage().allocation.get_individual().allocated
    return used, allocated

class DashboardMainPage(View):

    def get(self, request):
        used_space = get_user_space_info()[0]
        allocated_space = get_user_space_info()[1]
        return render(request, 'analyzer/dashboard.html',
                      {'used_space': used_space, 'allocated_space': allocated_space})
```

Urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', views.DashboardMainPage.as_view(), name='dashoard'),
]
```

Comment: In `get_user_info` you call `make_connection_to_user` without an argument. `make_connection_to_user` expects an argument to be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
used = make_connection_to_user().users_get_space_usage().used
```

This calls `make_connection_to_user()` with no arguments, but you defined it as requiring one argument:

```
def make_connection_to_user(request):
   ...
```